# Como alterar campos do formulário dependendo do usuário

Tags: python, flask

Estou usando Flask Admin e Flask security para o login no mesmo. Eu consigo sem problema nenhum definir dependendo da role de um usuário se ele pode ou não criar um objeto, porém eu gostaria de também poder adicionar ou retirar campos do formulário de criação/edição dependendo dessa role, é possível?

Tentei alterar o campo `form_columns` para uma `property` mas sempre que eu acesso o `current_user` nesse ou em outro campo de `form` ele ainda está `None` e portanto não posso realizar controle nenhum.

Answer (score 0):

Eu resolvi perguntar pois estava a alguns dias procurando uma resposta mas não havia encontrado, hoje consegui encontrar uma no stackoverflow em inglês, caso alguém tenha interesse segue o link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532988/hiding-fields-in-flask-admin-depending-on-logged-in-user

Peço desculpas pela pergunta que já havia uma resposta em outro stack.